# Unable to serve ember-cli app with http-serve

Tags: ember-cli

I created a plain vanilla app using ember-cli v 3.0.0 and added a route to it. When I build the app and serve it using ember-serve, all routes are loaded successfully. However, when I change working working directory to dist and serve it using http-serve, none of the routes load.

Is there any specific configuration required for serving the app through http-serve (or any similar web server)?

The app is on public repo at GitHub on https://github.com/shubmittal/testemberapp.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get things working by changing the location type to hash and prepending # to all hrefs. The link-to helper automatically handled the hash.

Answer (score 0):

Although Ember CLI uses the term “serve”, that’s actually only geared toward running a local server on your computer (but not acting as a web server for you).

So after having run `ember build —environment=production`, you can take the contents of the `dist` folder and put them on any web server you like. To test that, if you open the `dist/index.html` file in a web browser everything should work fine.

Does that help? I see people periodically hit that snag in understanding, you are definitely not the first ...

Comment: Isn't http-serve acting as the web server only? I am trying to run from dist directory by running http-serve in that location.

Comment: Ah, looks like `http-serve` is supposed to do all fallbacks, but that stops being an Ember question ;-) Per the readme, it looks like it redirects to `/`. If it actually **redirects** to `/` instead of rendering your index file from all locations, it would explain your issues. What you *need* to have happen is for it to serve Ember regardless of request and then you'll be set